# How to make 64 bit dll compatible with 64-bit editions of Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, compatibility, x86-64

I have compiled a dll on Windows Server 2008 64 bit edition. It works fine on that version of Windows, but if I switch to Windows 7 or XP 64 bit edition the dll does not work. How can I make the dll compatible with all three versions of 64bit edition windows?

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You likely have a dependency on some DLL or other similar thing. Try Process Monitor to see what fails.

Comment: He does, the DLL version of the CRT no doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a program called [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what dependencies your .dll file has, and eliminate the ones that are different between versions of Windows.

Comment: I've tried that can u  guide me where to place the the dlls in the either in the c:\windows\wow64system or the root folder where the dll is placed

Answer (score 2):

Check how `_WIN32_WINNT` and `WINVER` macros were defined in your DLL. To make your DLL compatible with Windows XP you should define them as `0x0501`. That lets you find all dependency problems at compile time. More information about these macros you could find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: well in the linker settings under project settings use it is defined  as WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;ADHANDLLERDLL_EXPORTS and also i am   using SECURITY_WIN32 and WIN32_DCOM macros no _WIN32_WINNT and WINVER are defined in i think. I there is any ay to make the dll depend-less of any other os dlls?

Comment: Check `stdafx.h`, it could be defined there still. If `_WIN32_WINNT` wasn't defined explicitly then it will be set by the compiler to the highest possible value for the OS where you compile your DLL.